# Which word should I use to express "done" for following someone on instagram?

Tags: translation

Someone asked me to follow him on Instagram. I want to say to him something like "done", or "did it".

Should I use やった、した、完了…？

Comment: "I want to **say him** something" is obviously incorrect... A native English speaker (@user385...) edited it to "I want to say **to** him something"... I don't see why you had to edit it back to "I want to say him something..." (?_?)

Comment: @Chocolate sorry haha, I re edited it

Answer (score 2):

If you're not close: しました（よ）。

Otherwise, or if you like to sound very casual: した（よ）。

Answer (score 1):

In this case I think やりました！ might be the most appropriate. Colloquial, but still polite.

please keep in mind i'm not a native speaker, it's just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the social network, the term can change : if you follow someone on Twitter or Instagram, you can say フォローしました which comes from the English verb "to follow" obviously. For a channel subscription, like on YouTube, the word 登録 (which means "subscription") suits better so you should say 「チャンネル登録しました」(I just subscribed to your channel).